# keycloak.exceptions.KeycloakGetError: 404: b'' using Python 3.7

Tags: python, keycloak

When I try to create new client/realm role, Im geting:

```
File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/untitled1/kc/code/keycloak_gab/x.py", line 28, in <module>
y = admin.create_client_role(payload=x, skip_exists='test')
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\keycloak\keycloak_admin.py", line 713, in create_client_role
    return raise_error_from_response(data_raw, KeycloakGetError, expected_code=201, skip_exists=skip_exists)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\keycloak\exceptions.py", line 102, in raise_error_from_response
    response_body=response.content)
keycloak.exceptions.KeycloakGetError: 404: b''
```

Thats my sample of source code:

```
    admin = KeycloakAdmin(server_url=server_addres,
                       username=user_n,
                       password=passw,
                       realm_name=realm,
                       verify=True)
x = admin.get_clients()[4]['id'] #['clientId']
y = admin.create_client_role(payload=x, skip_exists='test')
```

This client was generated using [aws.saml-metadata.xml-](https://signin.aws.amazon.com/static/saml-metadata.xml), i gave him full scope allowed, however this line doesnt work on any client that i made...

i have dependecies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bug fixed in the version 0.14.4:

```
from keycloak import KeycloakAdmin

admin = KeycloakAdmin(server_url='https://server-url',
                  username='username',
                  password='password',
                  realm_name='realm',
                  verify=True)


client_id = admin.get_clients()[4]['id']

role = admin.create_client_role(client_role_id=client_id,
                            payload={'name': 'roleName', 'clientRole': True},
                            skip_exists='test')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using `client` payload (response from `get_clients()`) instead of `client_role` (which is required payload for `create_client_role()`). You are mixing `client` and `client_role` payload types.

Comment: im not sure... in documentation i didnt found nothing about "client_role", however in library i found a comment in `create_client_role`: `:param payload: id of client (not client-id), role_name: name of role`
Im not sure, but i thing its a trouble with versions. library created in oct 25, and keycloak 4.6 in 14 nov...